# Quarto revealjs image only renders when viewing presentation on localhost

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I am having an issue with Quarto's presentation system. I am including an image in on my title slide with

```
title: "Presentation Title"
title-slide-attributes:
  data-background-image: /images/title_slide.jpg
  data-background-size: cover
  data-background-opacity: "0.5"
author:
  name: "Gabe"
  affiliation: UCSB
format:
  revealjs:
    slide-number: true
    chalkboard:
      buttons: false
    preview-links: auto
    theme: serif
```

in my YAML. When I render the file and it auto-launched in the browser, the image shows up fine. When I then go to view the saved .html file, the image no longer shows up, even though all other images in the presentation remain. I have included the format options in my YAML in case they might direct someone to the issue.

Any help on this would be great! Thank you.

I have tried using non-relative file path, changing file format, reducing file size, different browser. None of these work and I cannot wrap my head around why it would work on localhost but not as a stand-alone.